# How can i show only content type fields in block or how can i call a add content type page in a block

Tags: entities, blocks, nodes

How can i call a add node "content type" in a block.
I have upload an image below Image1.

[image]

I have a content type : `Upload Resume` ie `upload_resume`

Anomynous users can also only `create` this content type.

I want this fields in a block where user can upload resume not in page style bcos of below image shows other factors ie Image2

[image]

### Updated Image after Oscar answer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your module: [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock). And here is a quote about it from the module's project page):

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for including forms on panels.

Comment: thanks that what i am looking for. but i have a another issue i have updated in the question. have a look

Comment: That is what a not login see?

Comment: Oh! great, i hideout those using CSS.. But seems there is a problem with functionality.. i am working on it. i will let you know soon if error occurs